# Add EditText on the check event of radiobutton in android

Tags: android, radio-group

I have my android layout which has two radiobutton in one Radiogroup. I have these following conditions in my code:

If I checked first radio button then one editText should appear.

If I checked second radio button then two editText should appear.

I have pasted my code here...In my code editText is not appear when i m clicking on the either of the radio button.

```
package com.example.audio111;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Audioactivity extends Activity {
    String value;
    String selection;

    RadioGroup rg;
    int pos;
    int pos1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

         rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId){
                    case R.id.radio0:
                        // do operations specific to this selection (adding your EditText)
                        RelativeLayout mRlayout = new RelativeLayout(Audioactivity.this);
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mRparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        EditText myEditText = new EditText(Audioactivity.this);
                        mRparams.leftMargin=270;
                        mRparams.topMargin=150;
                        myEditText.setWidth(32);
                        myEditText.setEms(50);
                        myEditText.setLayoutParams(mRparams);
                        mRlayout.addView(myEditText);

                    break;

                    case R.id.radio1:
                        // do operations specific to this selection (adding two EditTexts)
                    break;

                }
             }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting correct pos?

Answer (score 1):

You added the `EditTexts` to `RelativeLayout`, *fine*.

But those `RelativeLayouts` are also generated dynamically. You need to add them in parent layout, too.

Something like:

```
LinearLayout linLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container)    //your xml's container layout
    rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            switch(checkedId){
                case R.id.rdbutton0:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Clicked moveable",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RelativeLayout mRlayout = new RelativeLayout(Audioactivity.this);
                    .
                    .
                    mRlayout.addView(myEditText);
                    linLayout.addView(mRlayout);    //add the newly created elativeLayout to your container Layout
                break;

                case R.id.rdbutton1:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Clicked fixed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RelativeLayout mRlayout1 = new RelativeLayout(Audioactivity.this);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mRparams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    .
                    .
                    mRlayout1.addView(myEditText2);
                    linLayout.addView(mRlayout1);    //add the newly created elativeLayout to your container Layout
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think both ways for getting selected RadioButtons you are using are not correct. Why don't you try with the 'standard' way to do this?

```
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch(checkedId){
            case R.id.radio0:
                // do operations specific to this selection (adding your EditText)
            break;

            case R.id.radio1:
                // do operations specific to this selection (adding two EditTexts)
            break;

        }
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.radio0:
                mEditText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEditText2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case R.id.radio1:
                mEditText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEditText2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```